# Pass a variable at build time into externalNativeBuild in Android

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-ndk

Is there a way to pass a constant at compile time into the **externalNativeBuild** gradle enclosure, and to be able to use it in code?

For example:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        arguments "-DTEST=" + rootProject.ext.value
    }
}
```

And the to be able to use it somehow like next:

```
void foo() {
   int bla = TEST;
   ....
}
```

Note that the above code is not working, as TEST is not recognized by the c++ compiler, which is what I am trying to solve.

Comment: Add `option(TEST "Test macro" 0 )` to your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @marcinj I've tried this suggestion but when I try to use TEST in actual C++ code it gives me a <use of undeclared identifier 'TEST'>

Comment: yes, that was not enough, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution will be to use `add_definitions`:

```
add_definitions(-DTEST=${TEST})
```

to your CMakeLists.txt file.

Another one would be to use [configuration file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html)

Basing on Native sample app from Android Studio:

1. Create file: config.h.in in the same folder as default native-lib.cpp with following contents:

   ```
   #ifndef NATIVEAPP1_CONFIG_H_IN
   #define NATIVEAPP1_CONFIG_H_IN

   #cmakedefine TEST ${TEST}

   #endif //NATIVEAPP1_CONFIG_H_IN
   ```
2. In CMakeLists.txt add:

   ```
   # This sets cmake variable to the one passed from gradle.
   # This TEST variable is available only in cmake but can be read in
   # config.h.in which is used by cmake to create config.h
   set(TEST ${TEST}) 

   configure_file( config.h.in ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated/config.h )
   include_directories( ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated/ )
   ```

(add it for example, above `add_library` call)

3. Finally, add `#include "config.h"` in you cod (ex. in native-lib.cpp) to use `TEST` macro.
4. Rebuild